# can't view records stored in DB in a web page

Tags: java, mysql, rest, jpa, thymeleaf

I'm referring to this guide (http://jvmhub.com/2015/08/09/spring-boot-with-thymeleaf-tutorial-part-3-spring-data-jpa/), the only difference is that i unified the classes PostEntity and Post assuming the name PostEntity.

When i try to store data in db through a form the applications works  but it can't allow me to view stored data in a webpage as showed in the guide linked above.
The web page result.html is displayed as

```
"Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jul 05 14:25:42 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "PostEntity.title" (template: "result" - line 11, col 9)"
```

and the console shows the exception:

**org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'title' cannot be found on null**

It is throwed even with the other attributes (id and content) according to the order they are disposed in result.html.

If i try to print the content of records variable to the console it shows that it is not null so i can't figure out why there is this exception.

Controller:

```
@Controller

public class Home {
@Autowired  private PostRepository  postRepository; 

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("post", new PostEntity());
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewPost( PostEntity post, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "index";
    }

    postRepository.save(post);
    List<PostEntity> records = (List<PostEntity>) postRepository.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("posts", records);
            return "redirect:result";
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/result", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAllPosts(Model model) {
     List<PostEntity> records = (List<PostEntity>) postRepository.findAll();
        for (PostEntity record : records) {
            System.out.println(record);
        }
    model.addAttribute("posts",  records);
    return "result"; 
 }
}
```

Model class:

```
@Entity
public class PostEntity {

public PostEntity() {}

public PostEntity(String title, String content) {
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int id;

public String title;

public String content;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}
}
```

index:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, part 2 - forms</h3>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${post}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}">Title error message</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Content:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}">Content error message</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, part 3 - SPRING DATA JPA</h3>
    <p th:each="PostEntity : ${posts}">
        <h4>Title:</h4>
         <div th:text="${PostEntity.title}"/></div>
        <h4>ID:</h4>
         <div th:text="${PostEntity.id}"/></div>
        <h4>Content:</h4>
         <div th:text="${PostEntity.content}"/></div>
        <div>---------------------------------------------------------</div>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the line System.out.println(record) write to the server-output? Maybe the cast on the findAll()-result already fails?

Comment: the cast is correct because is printed to console a string which refers to database. (the string is of this type: @a2350) i don't remember the exact string because i cannot try to run my application now.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this redirect-thing. When doing this your objects added to the model doesn't reach the further process. I remember running into similar trouble.

Comment: I tried to replace "redirect: result" with only "result" but the issue is still not solved. I wonder if the print in showall method is not null why  model.addAttribute("posts",  records) doesnt work?

Comment: Oh wait a second. Could you please change the result.html code to valid HTML? You are using self-closing tags (<div />) and additionally close them (</div>).

Comment: i have tried to change it  but nothing is changed. I don't think it's HTML's problem, the exception refers to a specific expression: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "PostEntity.title"